# JSF 2.0 Ajax and javascript reloading

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

I use JSF Ajax on my menu links to load the content of the page.
content is loaded with ui:insert and ui:composition with template attribute.
ajax is work and load the content with no reloadin the all page but I have a problem with my java scripts.

when I click menu Items the script reload with every new ajax request.
what should I do to prevent script reloading?

Comment: Is there anyone know this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your problem clearly, but maybe you should try to play with the rendered attribute of the `h:outputScript` component, for instance:

```xml
<h:outputScript library="js" name="ajax-util.js" 
                rendered="#{myBean.renderAjaxFunctions}" />
```